# What are the differences between Conda and Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

**Post-question update:**

See [Introduction to Conda](https://geohackweek.github.io/Introductory/01-conda-tutorial/) for more details.

---

**The problem:**

I first installed *Anaconda* on my ubuntu at `~/anaconda`, when I was trying to update my anaconda, according to the [documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html) from Continuum Analytics, I should use the following commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Then I realized that I did not have *conda* installed, so I installed it using the documentation from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html#update-anaconda-to-latest-version).

After *conda* is installed, when I run `conda update anaconda`, I got the following error:

> Error: package 'anaconda' is not installed in /home/xiang/miniconda

It appears conda is assuming my anaconda is installed under `/home/xiang/miniconda` which is *NOT* true.

**The questions:**

1. What are the differences between *conda* and *anaconda*?
2. How can I tell *conda* where my *anaconda* is installed?

Comment: See this post for the related question of [Anaconda vs. miniconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda/45421527).

Answer (score 264, accepted):

conda is the package manager. Anaconda is a set of about a hundred packages including conda, numpy, scipy, ipython notebook, and so on.

You installed Miniconda, which is a smaller alternative to Anaconda that is just conda and its dependencies, not those listed above.

Once you have Miniconda, you can easily install Anaconda into it with `conda install anaconda`.

Comment: And would you recommend doing so?

Comment: @Archie, it depends on what you want. See e.g., [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421527/5201771)

Answer (score 108):

#### Brief

`conda` is both a command line tool, and a python package.

Miniconda installer = Python + `conda`

Anaconda installer = Python + `conda` + meta package `anaconda`

meta Python pkg `anaconda` = about 160 other Python packages for daily use in data science

Anaconda installer = Miniconda installer + `conda install anaconda`

#### Detail

`conda` is an environment manager and a package manager. It means the tool itself. `conda` makes it possible to

- install package with `conda install flake8`
- create an environment with any version of Python with `conda create -n myenv python=3.6`

`conda` is not a binary command, is a **Python package**. To make `conda` work, you have to create a Python environment and install package `conda` into it. This is where Anaconda installer and Miniconda installer comes in.

Installer Minoconda installs a Python and the package `conda`. Installer Anaconda not only does what Miniconda does, it also install a **meta** Python package named `anaconda` for you.

> Meta packages, are packages that do NOT contain actual softwares and simply depend on other packages to be installed.

The actual 160+ python packages included in pkg `anaconda` are listed in `info/recipe/meta.yaml` in its [source file](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda/files).

```yaml
package:
    name: anaconda
    version: '2019.07'
build:
    ignore_run_exports:
        - '*'
    number: '0'
    pin_depends: strict
    string: py36_0
requirements:
    build:
        - python 3.6.8 haf84260_0
    is_meta_pkg:
        - true
    run:
        - alabaster 0.7.12 py36_0
        - anaconda-client 1.7.2 py36_0
        - anaconda-project 0.8.3 py_0
        # ...
        - beautifulsoup4 4.7.1 py36_1
        # ...
        - curl 7.65.2 ha441bb4_0
        # ...
        - hdf5 1.10.4 hfa1e0ec_0
        # ...
        - ipykernel 5.1.1 py36h39e3cac_0
        - ipython 7.6.1 py36h39e3cac_0
        - ipython_genutils 0.2.0 py36h241746c_0
        - ipywidgets 7.5.0 py_0
        # ...
        - jupyter 1.0.0 py36_7
        - jupyter_client 5.3.1 py_0
        - jupyter_console 6.0.0 py36_0
        - jupyter_core 4.5.0 py_0
        - jupyterlab 1.0.2 py36hf63ae98_0
        - jupyterlab_server 1.0.0 py_0
        # ...
        - matplotlib 3.1.0 py36h54f8f79_0
        # ...
        - mkl 2019.4 233
        - mkl-service 2.0.2 py36h1de35cc_0
        - mkl_fft 1.0.12 py36h5e564d8_0
        - mkl_random 1.0.2 py36h27c97d8_0
        # ...
        - nltk 3.4.4 py36_0
        # ...
        - numpy 1.16.4 py36hacdab7b_0
        - numpy-base 1.16.4 py36h6575580_0
        - numpydoc 0.9.1 py_0
        # ...
        - pandas 0.24.2 py36h0a44026_0
        - pandoc 2.2.3.2 0
        # ...
        - pillow 6.1.0 py36hb68e598_0
        # ...
        - pyqt 5.9.2 py36h655552a_2
        # ...
        - qt 5.9.7 h468cd18_1
        - qtawesome 0.5.7 py36_1
        - qtconsole 4.5.1 py_0
        - qtpy 1.8.0 py_0
        # ...
        - requests 2.22.0 py36_0
        # ...
        - sphinx 2.1.2 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib 1.0 py36_1
        - sphinxcontrib-applehelp 1.0.1 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-devhelp 1.0.1 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp 1.0.2 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-jsmath 1.0.1 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-qthelp 1.0.2 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3 py_0
        - sphinxcontrib-websupport 1.1.2 py_0
        - spyder 3.3.6 py36_0
        - spyder-kernels 0.5.1 py36_0
        # ...
```

Seeing from the above info, pre-installed packages from meta pkg `anaconda` are mainly for web scraping and data science. Like `requests`, `beautifulsoup`, `numpy`, `nltk`, etc.

If you have a Miniconda installed, `conda install anaconda` will make it same as an Anaconda installation, except that the installation folder names are different.

Comment: absolutely liked how you explained the delta between each concept ! thank you

Comment: this is both very confusing and the clearest explanation. Beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

### The Name

The content of the this page in the updated OP is not official: https://geohackweek.github.io/Introductory/01-conda-tutorial/

Instead, see https://www.anaconda.com/blog/whats-in-a-name-clarifying-the-anaconda-metapackage

##### Continuum Analytics

On Jun 28, 2017, https://www.anaconda.com/blog/continuum-analytics-officially-becomes-anaconda:

> Today, Continuum Analytics changed its name to Anaconda.
> The name change reinforces our commitment to the Anaconda open source development community, the 4.5 million Anaconda users across the globe and customers of our Anaconda Enterprise Platform.

##### Anaconda

is a kind of snake:

[image]

##### conda

shortend from anaconda? (open source V.S. closed source? like .net  V.S. .net Framework, PowerShell V.S PowerShell Core?)

[image]
[image]

### Miniconda V.S Anaconda

> Think of Anaconda Distribution as a great starter toolbox and a reference set of tested software, but power users typically grow out of it,  preferring to install Miniconda.

There may be many useless packages (for some users) in anaconda, like
anaconda3/pkgs/transformers-4.24.0-py310h06a4308_0/

> Transformers provides thousands of pretrained models to perform tasks on different modalities such as text, vision, and audio

### On github

[image]

--Note that the logos of the organizations are different--

[image]

still alive:
[image]

[image]