# Tensor flow package installation in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

I have been successfully using PyCharm for my python work.All the packages can be easily installed by going to settings and then project interpreter but tensorflow installation is showing error.In suggestions it asked me to upgrade pip module.But even after that it shows error with following message:

"   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

I am able to install all other packages but error is with tensorflow only.I am using windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Tensorflow with Anaconda and PyCharm on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059934/using-tensorflow-with-anaconda-and-pycharm-on-windows)

Comment: TensorFlow does not support Python versions: 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 on windows 10. If you are using Python version 3.8, then you will not be able to install TensorFlow because you probably don't have the version for Python installed. You should install a lower version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `pip install tensorflow` in command line and post the output here. Tensorflow can be installed on Windows but the process is often annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You could also tried anaconda. It is has very nice UI and you could switch between different version.