# Pycharm Can't install TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm, conda

I cannot install tensorflow in pycharm on windows 10, though I have tried many different things:

1. went to settings > project interpreter and tried clicking the green plus button to install it, gave me the error: non-zero exit code (1) and told me to try installing via pip in the command line, which was successful, but I can't figure out how to make Pycharm use it when it's installed there
2. tried changing to a Conda environment, which still would not allow me to run tensorflow since when I input into the python command line: pip.main(['install', 'tensorflow']) it gave me another error and told me to update pip
3. updated pip then tried step 2 again, but now that I have pip 10.0.1, I get the error 'pip has no attribute main'. I tried reverted pip to 9.0.3 in the command line, but this won't change the version used in pycharm, which makes no sense to me. I reinstalled anaconda, as well as pip, and deleted and made a new project and yet it still says that it is using pip 10.0.1 which makes no sense to me

So in summary, I still can't install tensorflow, and I now have the wrong version of pip being used in Pycharm. I realize that there are many other posts about this issue but I'm pretty sure I've been to all of them and either didn't get an applicable answer or an answer that I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to follow the steps from "[Pycharm anaconda import tensor flow library issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866877/pycharm-anaconda-import-tensor-flow-library-issue)" for solve your issue ("You need to do these following steps:")

Comment: turns out I was confused as to what Anaconda actually is. I simply created the environment in pycharm with Anaconda, then went into the Anaconda terminal and installed tensorflow from there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what worked for is this;

1. I installed TensorFlow on the command prompt as an administrator using this command `pip install tensorflow`
2. then I jumped back to my pycharm and clicked the red light bulb pop-up icon, it will have a few options when you click it, just select the one that says install tensor flow. This would not install in from scratch but basically, rebuild and update your pycharm workspace to note the newly installed tensorflow